# In MySQL, how to force insert into table if column not exist in field list?

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert records into a new database. I have an old database that contains fields that are no longer in the new database.

So when I execute the insertion request I get this message (field 'contract' unknown in field list).

I know it's normal but I would like to ignore this message and force the insertion.

Comment: Are you using some tool for this or direclty a query?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. You need to re-write the query to match the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this using MYSQL alone

i have a php script i use for stripping out data that there is no column for in the database table

i use SHOW COLUMNS FROM table to find out what columns are available, i then strip the data out that does not match these columns and then build the insert query to insert the data in the database minus the unavailable columns

the down side is that if you want to keep something from the orignal data and there is no column for it in the new table, then it will be discarded.